# Any free APIs or ways to get site status updates?

Tags: linux, monitoring, reporting, hyperlink

Are there any foss tools, applications etc. which can be configured to monitor a site and see whether it is up or not. The user should be able to go to the site, see if there are any error codes and if there are then publish that data to a web-page and preferably have a graph so you can see over time about site-availability.

There are sites such as https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime and https://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ but they only give site info. the moment you go to them. This should have some sort of monitoring process which spiders every 30 minutes or so and see if it gets valid content or an HTTP Error code.

Comment: The easiest thing would be setting up a cron job to run e.g. all 30min which runs a `wget` or `curl` command against a page on the given website and evaluates the HTTP response code. Just thinking aloud :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use **[Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/)** for simple monitoring tasks:

Your requirements:

- Open Source
- Can Monitor a site to see whether it is up or not
- Publish that data to a web interface
- Presents graphs and statistics

More:

- Can monitor basically anything
- Send notification (e.g. emails) on certain events
- [much more](https://www.nagios.org/about/features/)

Try this [demo of the interface](http://nagioscore.demos.nagios.com/).

Comment: Nagios is the first thing I thought of when reading the question. It's sort f industry standard. There are lots of good books about it, plus web based utorials and YouTube

Answer (score 1):

Nagios has already been mentioned, so I wont' reiterate it here.  It really is essentially the industry standard right now.

The other possibility that comes to mind is [Netdata](http://my-netdata.io/).  It fits all your outlined requirements, and can actually do some pretty useful stuff for your particular use case (the HTTP server monitoring can issue arbitrary request types against arbitrary paths, and tracks not only response codes and the fact that the server is up, but also latency).  Quick info about the specific plugin and module relevant to your use case can be found [here](https://github.com/netdata/netdata/tree/master/collectors/python.d.plugin/httpcheck).  It also provides a reasonably easy to use alerting system, works in near real time (it's designed for collecting data every second with minimal overhead), and can monitor a whole lot of other things too without much difficulty.

Disclaimer: I'm an active member of the team that develops Netdata.

Comment: I will try both and hopefully revisit the question later.

Answer (score 0):

Most "status pages" like [statuspage.io](https://www.statuspage.io/) or [hund](https://www.hund.io/) include a mechanism for being notified of state changes.  You can get an email or merge this information into your own status page.  This is easy to get going without investing any more in your own infrastructure.